# Is it possible to plot rows of a matrix without a for loop?

Tags: matlab, plot

I have a matrix that stores multiple functions in its rows each evaluated against the interval `[0,20]`. I'm running through a `for` loop to output them at the moment. Is there a better way of doing this or is this the only way of doing it in MATLAB?

```
h = 0.1;
xLine = 0:h:20;
nGrid = length(xLine);

nu = [ 1, 2, 3 ];
nNu = length(nu);

b = zeros(nNu,nGrid);
for i=1:nNu
    b(i:i,1:nGrid) = besselj(nu(i), xLine);
end

hFig = figure(1);
hold on
set(hFig, 'Position', [1000 600 800 500]);
for i=1:nNu
    plot(xLine, b(i:i,1:nGrid))
end
```

Comment: plot(YourMatrix(:,1:end)) for each column and plot(YourMatrix(1:end,:)) for each row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `plot` vectorized.  Specifically, you can supply `b` directly into `plot` but you need to make sure that the larger of the two dimensions in `b` matches the total number of elements in the vector `xLine`.  This is what you have, so we're good. Therefore, because each unique signal occupies a row in your matrix, just supply `b` into your `plot` call and use it a single time.

```
hFig = figure(1);
hold on
set(hFig, 'Position', [1000 600 800 500]);
plot(xLine, b);
```

This will plot each row as a separate colour.  If you tried doing this, you'll see that the plots are the same in comparison to the `for` loop approach.

Check out the documentation for `plot` for more details: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html

Comment: Very nice thanks! I was wondering is there also a nicer way of filling the matrix b? Is there a way of specifying just the row to fill or do I have use the full indexing notation `b(i:i,1:nGrid) =`?

Comment: @Riggs You're welcome!  Unfortunately the first parameter has to be a scalar and so you need to use a loop...yup...sucks.  However, you can shorten the loop to just do this:  `for i = 1:nNu, b(i,:) = besselj(nu(i), xLine); end`.  It's slightly shorter, but it does the same trick.  You don't need to do `i:i`. That's superfluous.  Just use `i` by itself.  Also, instead of `1:nGrid`, just use `:`.  `xLine` has `nGrid` elements, so the output will implicitly be `nGrid` elements long.

Answer (score 2):

Replace for loop with:

```
plot(xLine, b(:,1:nGrid))
```

Note: I can't perfectly recall but some older versions of Matlab may want everything in columns and you'd want to transpose the matrices:

```
plot(xLine.', b(:,1:nGrid).')
```

Comment: My comment was nonsense.  It looks like that column stuff I talked about has changed.  This is good. +1.

Comment: @rayryeng Probably good style though to transpose b for compatibility.